# Unity does not inject dependency after configuring OAuth?

Tags: c#, oauth, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

Hi Guys I am very new to the Oauth and Identity so I tried configuring token based authentication using OAuth and i am able to generate the token but Strange thing is after i configure the OAuth my Unity dependency stopped working and It does not inject dependency anymore instead gives an exception "Object instance not set to an instance of an object"

My new startup.cs class that runs when i run the application looks like this.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {  
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);         
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();

    }
```

I know it has to do something with **ordering of these configuration** but I tried different other possible orders, but had no luck at all. The     **WebApiConfig.Register(config)** looks like this

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();            
        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    }
```

Now the part that does not work is when I use the dependency in the controllers which worked well before..

The exception looks like this

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
at MIS.WebAPI.Controllers.ProductController.GetAll() in E:\\MIS (2)\\MIS\\MIS.WebAPI\\Controllers\\ProductController.cs:line 27
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

This is the ProductController.cs class

```
namespace MIS.WebAPI.Controllers
{
[EnableCors(origins:"*",headers:"*",methods:"*")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Product
    [Dependency]
    public IProductRepository _productRepo { get; set; }
    [Route("api/getAllProduct")]
    public Response GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _productRepo.GetALl();
            return Response.Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Response.BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always add the full stack trace (of exception and *all* inner exception) to the question.

Comment: @Steven: Sorry but the inner exception is null and the stack trace just gives the line number where it encountered exception...

Comment: That's because you are encountering a "first chance exception". Press F5 to let the application continue. This will result in an exception with a full stack trace. Without the supplied information it will be very hard for anyone to get an idea where things are going wrong and it will be hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: @Steven : Aight..! the exception looks like this

Comment: The exception is thrown from within your `ProductController.GetAll()`. It should be easy to find out which reference is null.

Comment: @Steven: Sorry that I missed out an important part in the question if you see above then the problem is not within the GetAll().. but the unity container is not able to inject dependency on the  _productRepo during runtime.. so it is throwing that exception.. so my question is even though I have configured Unity and registered all types the dependency is not being injected during runtime... So like i said initially is it because of the order of configurations in the Startup file?

Comment: The exception tells us otherwise. What's happening at line 27 of your ProductController.cs?